# Binding - JAXB : XJC Doesn't generate Enum class for an attribute

Tags: binding, jaxb, enumeration, xjc, complextype

I have a problem with the XJC tool that it doesn't generate an Enum class for the attribute myEnum using this schema.

```
<xs:element name="myClass"> 
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="myEnum" >
            <xs:simpleType >
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but it generates it if I use only this

```
<xs:simpleType >
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

here is the external binding file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
     version="2.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     > 
<globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName">

</globalBindings>  
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this: define a small XSD file with just that particular type declared as a global type, e.g.:

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="myEnumSimpleType">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
     </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="myClass"> 
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="myEnum" type="myEnumSimpleType">
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

That will generate a JAXB class (let's call it the 'artificial JAXB class).

Then you can run xjc on the larger XSD and customize the generation to make use of this type for the particular elements.

Alternately, if the JAXB generation from this external XSD is a one-time operation (and then you put the JAXB-generated code in your SVN/Git for instance), then you can rewrite that potion of the code to use your 'artificial' JAXB type instead.

Another you may want to try is to have your binding customization

```
<globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName">
```

not be a global one, but use expression to try to nail it exactly on this type. It is likely that JAXB will generate a new class for each occurrence, even though they are going to be the same.

Since I find xpath tedious, I would test it out quickly on a local copy of that big XSD, that you modify with the  namespace, e.g.

```xml
<xs:element name="myClass"> 
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="myEnum" >
        <xs:simpleType >
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
     </xs:attribute>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thaank you for your answer but the problem is that I have to work on an xsd file (already exist) with more than 1500 lines

Comment: Are you saying you can't change the XSD (and therefore are looking for an XJC-only solution) ? Otherwise, can you please explain why the size matters in this case ? Also, I'd recommend you give out details about your particualr setup: JDK and JAXB version+implementation in particular.

Comment: Yes I can't change the XSD (XSD from another vendor)
I use the JDK 6 and JAXB 2.2 , I'am trying to generate automatically xml files(filled with random data) from xsd files. thank you